# Django 1.5 pagination with Raw Query Set

Tags: python, django, pagination

I'm trying to implement Django's built in pagination feature with a raw query set.  I've researched the issue and the answer is I need to cast my set as a list.  Something like this:

paginator = Paginator((list(set)), 10)

The issue is I'm still receiving the "RawQuerySet has no len() operation" error which leads me to believe that I'm missing something.  I have a few questions about how to implement pagination with this change.

In my html template I have the standard pagination tags surrounding my object iteration.  Does implementing the suggested fix involve more than just adding the above line of code to my views.py?

views.py

```
refg = RefGene.objects.raw(qrefg)

paginator = Paginator(refg, 100) # Show 100 contacts per page
paginator._count = len(list(refg))

# using django's generated forms
c = RequestContext(request, {
    "refg": refg,
     ...
 })

return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

html template

```
{% autopaginate refg %}
{% for r in refg %}

    <tr>
    <td>{{ r.data}}</td>
    <td>{{ r.loc}}</td>
    </tr>

{% endfor %}
{% paginate %}
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the relevant view code?

Comment: Updated the question with code.

Comment: Read this one: stackoverflow.com/questions/5152984/django-pagination-and-rawqueryset

Comment: creating a list is too expensive . You might want to run another query  to get the count.

Comment: I've done what is posted in the above SO link, yet I still am not able to paginate. I'm not concerned with optimization, I just need to be able to paginate the large query set.